# Does Mark Twain mean that it's not safe to leave your wife and a Frenchman alone?

Tags: meaning, mark-twain

Is it safe to leave your wife and a Frenchman alone? It would seem it isn't according to Mark Twain, or is there another way of interpreting this?:

> ***A Frenchman's home is where another man's wife is.***  — ([*Notebooks and
> Journals*](https://www.ucpress.edu/book/9780520025424/mark-twains-notebooks-and-journals-volume-ii), *#18, Feb.- Sept. 1879*)

Comment: What is your specific question? The meaning of the passage? Or the truth of the opinion stated?

Comment: It's playing on the reputation of the French (among English speakers) for being 'naughty' (free-and-easy with regard to sex).

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close this—understanding the joke depends on knowing how 19th-century Americans stereotyped the French, which may not be common knowledge 150 years later.

Comment: @bobble Exactly, If the meaning is a corollary of the truth.

Comment: @KateBunting *"It's playing on the reputation of the French (among English speakers)"* native English speakers in general or American English speakers particularly?

Comment: @al-Mu'tamid asking for whether, in the real world, this stereotype is true, is not on-topic. Asking for what this passage was intended to mean is, by contrast, on-topic. **Which question do you mean to ask**?

Comment: @bobble the latter, hence *"is there another way of interpreting this?"*. On a side note, I'd like to thank you for your edits of [Has the Athenian purpose of tragic narratives been embedded in contemporary tragedies?] sadly it didn't escape the guillotine for us to enjoy the harvest of your labour.

Comment: Ptah-hotep - If I had meant 'only Americans' I would have said so! I don't know about Australia, but it was certainly a cliché in 19th and early 20th century Britain.